# Is AWS TCO calculator no longer active?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cost-management

AWS TCO calculator service is no longer findable under any AWS service.
I cannot find neither reason nor explanation why this has been done and where the old TCO calculator can be found now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on a lot of customer feedback, the AWS TCO Calculator has been replaced by the AWS Pricing Calculator. Please have a look at [this blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/check-it-out-new-aws-pricing-calculator-for-ec2-and-ebs/) to learn how you can estimate your EC2 and EBS cost using the new calculator.

Comment: AWS Pricing Calculator you mention above is replacement for obsolete (since June 30th 2020) Simple Monthly Calculator, but it is not replacement for AWS TCO Calculator  which was in question and allowed to compare AWS Costs with on-premises costs. I can only guess that comparison results were shocking prospective enterprise AWS customers and was abused by sysadmins, that's why AWS buried that calculator.

Comment: Looks like the logic for AWS TCO calculator now resides in the [Migration Evaluator](https://aws.amazon.com/migration-evaluator/). The tool to 'Build a data-driven business case for AWS'.

Comment: I second @EricD.'s answer, here is the [AWS whitepaper](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/how-aws-pricing-works/aws-pricingtco-tools.html#aws-pricing-calculator) that explicitly states that the Migration Evaluator holds the logic that once belonged to the TCO calculator